# How do I make this If statement work with everything?

Tags: java, calculator

For my program I am trying to make a simple calculator that does two number addition, subtraction, multiplication and division but I am hitting a road block with my if statement. How do I make this Statement work with my choice string but also work with my addition, subtraction, multiplication and division string? I am using Java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calculator
{

public static void main (String args [])
{
    String MainMenu = " Calculator Options \n\n1. Addition\n2" +
    " Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Exit";

    menu (MainMenu);
}

 public static String menu (String info)
{
    String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (info);
    return choice;

}


{
if (choice.equals ("1"))
  Add();
    else
       if (choice.equals ("2"))
        Sub();
          else
            if (choice.equals ("3"))
             Mult();
               else 
                if (choice.equals ("4"))
                 Div();
}


public static int Addition (String Add)
{
    String add1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 1 is?");
    int numadd1 = Integer.parseInt (add1);

    String add2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 2 is?");
    int numadd2 = Integer.parseInt (add2);

    int addEquals = numadd1 + numadd2;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Answer Is: " + addEquals);

    return addEquals;
}

public static int Subtraction (String Sub)
{
    String sub1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 1 is?");
    int numsub1 = Integer.parseInt (sub1);

    String sub2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 2 is?");
    int numsub2 = Integer.parseInt (sub2);

    int subEquals = numsub1 - numsub2;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Answer Is: " + subEquals);

    return subEquals;
}

public static int Multiplication (String Mult)
{
    String mult1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 1 is?");
    int nummult1 = Integer.parseInt (mult1);

    String mult2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 2 is?");
    int nummult2 = Integer.parseInt (mult2);

    int multEquals = nummult1 * nummult2;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Answer Is: " + multEquals);

    return multEquals;
}

public static int Divistion (String Div)
{
    String div1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 1 is?");
    int numdiv1 = Integer.parseInt (div1);

    String div2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 2 is?");
    int numdiv2 = Integer.parseInt (div2);

    int divEquals = numdiv1 / numdiv2;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Answer Is: " + divEquals);

    return divEquals;
}
}
```

Comment: To make your if's work with everything, it must obtain enlightenment, becoming ONE WITH EVERYTHING!

Comment: ...said the Dalai Lama in a pizza store.

Comment: Why does it have to be at most 1 if block that needs to work with everything? Programs can have many of them

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems with your code, so here's a revised version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mainMenu = " Calculator Options \n\n1. Addition\n2" +
            " Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Exit";

    String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainMenu);

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number 1 is?"));
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number 2 is?"));

    int result;
    if (choice.equals("1")) {
        result = num1 + num2;
    } else if (choice.equals("2")) {
        result = num1 - num2;
    } else if (choice.equals("3")) {
        result = num1 * num2;
    } else if (choice.equals("4")) {
        result = num1 / num2;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Answer Is: " + result);
}
```

This would be a bit cleaner with a `switch`, but I've used `if`s per your requirement.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much I did not notice that it could become that simple me and my partner were over thinking it way to much but looking at what you said really does make sense

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's what I did to fix it:

1. Move the if block into the main method: as it is it can't compile
2. Change method calls to match method names
3. Remove method parmeter - they aren't needed as you're getting the values from the JOptionPane
4. Change main to return and int.

Nice app you go there ~ Cheers

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main (String args []) {
        String MainMenu = " Calculator Options \n\n1. Addition\n2" +
                " Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Exit";
        menu (MainMenu);
    }

    public static int menu (String info) {
        String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (info);

        if (choice.equals ("1"))
            return Addition();
        else if (choice.equals ("2"))
            return Subtraction();
        else if (choice.equals ("3"))
            return  Multiplication();
        else if (choice.equals ("4"))
            return  Division();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public static int Addition () {
        String add1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 1 is?");
        int numadd1 = Integer.parseInt (add1);

        String add2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 2 is?");
        int numadd2 = Integer.parseInt (add2);

        int addEquals = numadd1 + numadd2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Answer Is: " + addEquals);

        return addEquals;
    }

    public static int Subtraction ()
    {
        String sub1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 1 is?");
        int numsub1 = Integer.parseInt (sub1);

        String sub2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 2 is?");
        int numsub2 = Integer.parseInt (sub2);

        int subEquals = numsub1 - numsub2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Answer Is: " + subEquals);

        return subEquals;
    }

    public static int Multiplication ()
    {
        String mult1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 1 is?");
        int nummult1 = Integer.parseInt (mult1);

        String mult2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 2 is?");
        int nummult2 = Integer.parseInt (mult2);

        int multEquals = nummult1 * nummult2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Answer Is: " + multEquals);

        return multEquals;
    }

    public static int Division ()
    {
        String div1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 1 is?");
        int numdiv1 = Integer.parseInt (div1);

        String div2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Number 2 is?");
        int numdiv2 = Integer.parseInt (div2);

        int divEquals = numdiv1 / numdiv2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Answer Is: " + divEquals);

        return divEquals;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider using a switch statement instead of these nested ifs.  If you made your operation choice a, b, c, d, then the default case could assume a number and try to parse it.

Comment: The only problem is that my teacher is making us use if statements so I do not know how to incorporate it with my menu String and all of the addition subtraction multiplication and division strings

Comment: Teachers who are teaching bad programming habits in an attempt to teach a concept. If the teacher can't come up with a real world application of said concept, then the teacher doesn't need to teach it. Teaching poor coding habits in an attempt to teach a concept will develop poor coding habits and the concept doesn't stick. I had too many professors in college like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while since I've written Java, but I think you have a few issues with the code as is.  First, your if statement is in an anonymous block.  Second, you are calling the method menu, which returns a value, but you aren't setting that value to anything.  D, you misspelled "Division."  Lastly, this won't cause the code to fail, but you are using capital letters for the first letter of methods.  I believe the normal way of writing Java applications is to capitalize classes, but methods are usually undercase first letter, CamelCase for the rest (packages are also usually undercase/CamelCase).  Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong.

Edit:
PS. I forgot, you are apparently calling the methods the wrong way (you can't call the "Addition" method with Add()) and as with the menu method, you aren't setting the value that is returned by the method to anything.

Comment: alright so i made some of the changes you said to do for examples the methods i lowercased and i respelled division, but the main thing i wondering is how do i make this if statement work. when i Compile an error pops up saying cannot find symbol - variable choice, but if i put the if statement in with the info string then it finds choice but not My add sub mult or div string how can i fix that problem?

Comment: P.S.S. An if, else if statement is one statement

Comment: See my edit, you are calling them by names that you didn't name them as.  Also, you aren't putting the parameters in the call as are required by the methods.

Comment: looks like you got your answers...so much for the teaching moment